# Putting page content in input value doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is what I'm trying to maintain:

I have two inputs, #e_adres and #e_nummer. When I click on #e_nummer, I want to do this query:
`mysql_query("SELECT b_nummer FROM km WHERE b_adres = '".$_GET['adres']."' ORDER BY nr DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());`

And I want the result of that query to become the value of my second input, #e_nummer.

So I've put this script in my page:

```
$( "#e_nummer" ).click(function() {
    var a = $('#e_adres').val();
    var g = $.get( "e_nummer.php", { adres: a } );
    $( "#e_nummer" ).val( g );
});
```

In e_nummer.php is the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("km") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `b_nummer` FROM `km` WHERE `b_adres` = '".$_GET['adres']."' ORDER BY `nr` DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
echo $row['b_nummer'];
```

But the value of the input becomes [object Object] instead of `$row['b_nummer']`. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: print value of var `g` in console.

Comment: any errors in output?

Comment: Just my two cents: mysql_* functions are outdated. Use PDO or MySQLi

Comment: No errors, those inputs are text inputs. It already works, thanks to Rajesh kakawat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
$( "#e_nummer" ).click(function() {
    var a = $('#e_adres').val();
   $.get( "e_nummer.php", { adres: a },function(data){
        $( "#e_nummer" ).val( data );
    });
})
```

Comment: You just made my day! You don't know for how long I've been struggling with this. Thanks a lot, it works. I will accept your answer in 9 minutes.